# django, authenticate only for user not super user

Tags: python, django

Im using django >= 3.0, how to create an authentication that allowed only for non-super user. I' am currently working on login part where a normal user can login but strict for those user that labled as is_superuser = True

```
def request(request):

    if len(request.POST) > 0 :

       # print(request.__class__.__name__);

       constraint = helpers.constraint(request);
       data = constraint.strict(["username", "password"], True);

       username = data['username'];
       password = data['password'];

       user = auth.authenticate(
           username = username,
           password = password
       );

       if user :
           print(user);
           breakpoint();

           auth.login(request,user)

           return HttpResponse("jkjhhj");

       messages.info(request, "Invalid credentials");

    return login(request);
```

Same like this....

```
user = auth.authenticate(
               username = username,
               password = password,
               is_superuser = False
           );
```

Comment: I don't clearly understand what you want, but you can exclude superusers like this before login: ```if not user.is_superuser:```